# Not able find proper link to download magento

Tags: php, magento, amazon-ec2, installation

I was kind of trying to install Magento on EC2 instance. I am trying to download it with the help of the following command.

```
wget http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.9.0.1/magento-1.9.0.1.tar.gz
```

I am not able to download Magento with this, I think this link has been expired. I have tried to find alternate sources for this but all sources had this type of URL only which are not working.

Can anybody hep me out with downloading Magento setup?

Comment: I also faced the same probllem, where I have downloaded the package from the magento site and then uploaded to the server but there are some modules missing in that package. dont know whats the problem

Comment: They used to allow this, but looks like it's all changed now.  I would suggest downloading on desktop, FTP ing to *A* server that you can pull it from

Comment: Or clone it from github - https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror

Comment: Those direct links are being discontinued. Go look into FireGento as a Magento 1.x repository.

Answer (score 0):

```
Open this  https://www.magentocommerce.com/download
And click on ' Release Archive '
```